# django error on 'django-admin makemigrations' command

Tags: django, migration

I am getting following error when run 'django-admin makemigrations' command

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

Comment: Did you mean to run python manage.py makemigrations ?

Comment: using python manage.py makemigrations solved my problem :) thanks :)